# latex: footnote in glossaries entry

Tags: latex, bibliography, glossaries

I need help with the latex glossaries package. I just need a footnote within a glossary entry.

Example:

```
\newglossaryentry{glos:vo}{
name=ValueObject,
description={a very good explanation for valueObject\footnote{S.89ff \cite{aBookInBibliography}}.}}
```

Texmaker refuses to build PDF. The log file is confusing as always, saying something like this:

> I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
>   control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
>   My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
>   ! Too many }'s.

So any ideas here? Thank you.

Comment: Ask question again on tex.stackexchange.com and you're more likely to get an answer.

Comment: thank you - next time I'll do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've got it. it has not been the fault of the footnote or cite. it turned out, my description text has been to long.

whysoever latex accepts description texts just with 1024 characters maximum.